# Regex to extract date and time from log

Tags: sed

```
echo "INFO|2016-11-06 18:44:07.577|G|SOME_THING_IN_CAPS|/something/pages1.html" | \
sed -rn "s/(.*\|)([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\ ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3})\2\3/p"
```

Hi Guys,

i am trying to extract the date and time from the line above. Can you tell me what is missing?

I get this error, not sure how to troubleshoot it

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 81: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: missing middle `/` char? i.e. `sed 's/..../\2\3/p'` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The is no substitution string in your command. The `s` command must contain 3 delimiters: `s/pattern/string/`.

Try this:

```
$ echo "INFO|2016-11-06 18:44:07.577|G|SOME_THING_IN_CAPS|/something/pages1.html" | sed -rn "s/.*\|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}).*/\1/p"
2016-11-0618:44:07.577
```

Moreover, as pointed out in comments:

- you just need one capturing group for date and time
- dots characters must be escaped in pattern (`\.[0-9]{3}`, not `.[0-9]{3}`), but not space characters (`{2} [0-9]`, not `{2}\ [0-9]`

Comment: you don't need the escaping of the space character, but you need the escaping of the dot character (milliseconds) if you want to be accurate (and you don't need to create a group for the first group, you could write `\1\2` after that. Otherwise, works.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` or `cut` is better suited for this task

```
$ s='INFO|2016-11-06 18:44:07.577|G|SOME_THING_IN_CAPS|/something/pages1.html'

$ echo "$s" | awk -F\| '{print $2}'
2016-11-06 18:44:07.577

$ echo "$s" | cut -d\| -f2
2016-11-06 18:44:07.577
```